# Error: "linker 'cc' not found" when cross compiling a rust project from windows to linux using cargo

Tags: linux, windows, rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I have a basic rust/cargo project with a single main file and some basic dependencies. The `cargo build` command works fine when the target is not specified (I am using windows so it builds to windows), but when I try to cross compile the program to linux using `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` or `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`, the process fails with the following error: `linker 'cc' not found`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get around this? Is there a specific linker I need to install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just figured it out.

It turns out you need to tell cargo to use the LLVM linker instead. You do this by creating a new directory called `.cargo` in your base directory, and then a new file called `config.toml` in this directory. Here you can add the lines:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
rustflags = ["-C", "linker-flavor=ld.lld"]
```

Then building with the command `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` should work!

Comment: So the above did not work for me (I got an error about missing lld) however the below did work.
`[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "rust-lld"`

Answer (score 6):

This post summarises the two responses of Yaxlat and Rory Sullivan - thank you both:

Create a file named config.toml in the newly created directory .cargo in your base directory.

This file has the following content:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "rust-lld"
```

Enter these two commands in the terminal

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

The executable binary for Linux is now in the target directory.